# using localstorage to keep html on page refresh not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I'm trying to integrate this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/ReT8n/ in a fiddle I'm doing:

https://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/99c8gn7k/

Basically you have a basket with some items inside of it, you can add or remove them. What I want is that, on page refresh, the `html()` of the `.basket` is kept in local storage. I'm stuck here:

https://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/z8cffk4c/

I've put the `forLocalStorage` variable in the click handler because otherwise, the var wouldn't update itself but now I'm guessing that the final local storage code

```
  if(localStorage.getItem('toDoData')) {
    forLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('toDoData');
}
```

is not working because it can't retrive the variable?

I've tried moving around things but I'm stuck here. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose that the localStorage is unavailable in the page context.

Comment: You do nothing once you set your forLocalStorage variable. It doesn't magically update your DOM respectively. You need to implement logic too: https://jsfiddle.net/z8cffk4c/9/

Comment: @A.Wolff if you want to answer i'll "accept" this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update DOM once your variable is set, e.g:

```
 // LOCAL STORAGEEEEEEEE
  if (localStorage.getItem('toDoData')) {
    forLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('toDoData');
    $('#cart').html(forLocalStorage);
    itemsCount();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Local storage can only store `string key value pairs`. I ensured you are passing in a string and also added a function to populate the cart on refresh, which resolved problems.

```
function populateCart() {
    var items = localStorage.getItem('toDoData') || '';
    $('#cart').html(items);
}
```

Added this call inside `document.ready`, like so: -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    populateCart();
    // rest of code
});
```

Working CodePen: http://codepen.io/owenayres/pen/oxKmZg

You can do some light reading [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) on local storage. It is, in my opinion, best practice to store the data for the HTML as some JSON in local storage, which you would then loop through and regenerate the HTML for when reading this data again.

Comment: can you post the fiddle? i did it but it's not workin :/

Comment: Your codepen doesn't work as expected and anyway, removing `toString()` works the same, with or without it. Or i really miss something...

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah sorry thanks - it was because I added `append` instead of `html()`... D'oh! It all works now, appreciate the heads-up.

Comment: "Local storage can only store strings"??Are you serious?[Really](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/storing-objects-html5-local-storage/)?

Comment: @anu that shows you how to stringify objects... So, yes. If you read my answer you'll see I actually recommend to use the JSON approach anyway, which would be better than storing HTML in local storage